# Trigger to update an Account everytime a related Opportunity's stage changes

Tags: trigger

I need to add a description on my Account every time an Opportunity's stage is changed.
I tried the following and getting NULL pointer exception.

```java
public class opportunityTriggerHandler {
    public static void oppStgChangeDetails(List<Opportunity> oppList, map<Id, Opportunity> oldmap, boolean isInsert, boolean isUpdate){
        List<Account> accsToUpdate = New List<Account>();

        for(Opportunity opp:oppList){
            if(isInsert || (isUpdate && opp.stageName <> oldmap.get(opp.Id).stageName)){
                opp.Account.Description = opp.Account.Description + 'Prev Stage: ' + oldmap.get(opp.Id).stageName 
                    + 'New Stage: ' + opp.StageName;
                accsToUpdate.add(opp.Account);
            }
        }
        update accsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Derek as it is easier to track Opportunity Stage changes on the Opportunity Stage history list and after a time it becomes absolutely cumbersome if there are many changes in Stages - imagine how bulky it will look if it is updated 10 - 20 times. Another thing to think about is that Account has one to many relationship with Opportunity, and what information you are maintaining at Account level does not indicate which Opportunity was updated. Again it will look messy when real users will use it.

However, if it is absolute must, may be you can persuade your clients to maintain just the last 3-5 changes in Stage at Account level with Opportunity data, where logic might be a little complicated but it will show just the most recent changes and have other changes still visible in Stage history related list.

Talking about the code - The reason you got NullPointerException is cause you were trying to access opp.Account.Description without querying on Account, which is not available at Opportunity level. The workaround is to get all Account Ids from Oppotunity and query on them to get description and reiterate on Opportunities to update Accounts. I have done that here in the code below:

```
public static void oppStgChangeDetails(List<Opportunity> oppList, map<Id, Opportunity> oldmap, boolean isInsert, boolean isUpdate){
    
    Set<Id> setAccounts = new Set<Id>();
    List<Account> accsToUpdate = New List<Account>();

    for(Opportunity opp:oppList) {
        if(isInsert || (isUpdate && opp.stageName <> oldmap.get(opp.Id).stageName)){
            setAccounts.add(opp.AccountId);
        }
    }

    Map<Id, Account> mapAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([Select Id, Description From Account Where Id IN: setAccounts]);

    for(Opportunity opp:oppList) {
        if(isInsert || (isUpdate && opp.stageName <> oldmap.get(opp.Id).stageName)){
            Account acc = new Account(  Id = opp.AccountId,
                                        Description = (mapAccounts.get(opp.AccountId).Description != null) ? mapAccounts.get(opp.AccountId).Description : '' + 
                                                     ' Prev Stage: ' + oldmap.get(opp.Id).stageName +
                                                     ' New Stage: ' + opp.StageName
                                    );
            accsToUpdate.add(acc);
        }
    }

    update accsToUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger context variables do not contain data on related objects. If you need related data, you need to explicitly query for it.

Continually appending to the Account's Description would end up giving you a long and messy description, and that's even before you consider that an Account can have multiple Opportunities. I'd argue that this information should not appear on the Account level, opting to just use the Opportunity Stage History related list (that Salesforce provides Out Of the Box) to convey this information.

If you insist though, you should just use the `AccountId` contained in your Opportunity along with the SObject constructor to create the Accounts to update.

```java
// A List would run into issues if you ever worked on 2 Opps for the same Account
//   at the same time
// A Map helps us avoid that problem
Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();

for(Opportunity opp :oppsList){
    // If the AccountId already exists in the map, we can just overwrite the existing
    //   value by calling .put() again
    accountsToUpdate.put(opp.AccountId, new Account(
        // SObject constructor takes field=value pairs
        // Id is one of the fields we can set (and is required
        //   if you want to be able to DML update)
        Id = opp.AccountId,
        Description = oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName + ' -> ' + opp.StageName
    );
}

update accountsToUpdate.values();
// but seriously, don't do this
// just use the Stage History related list to surface this information
```